# Discord.Js: Cannot read table issue

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a little Discord bot with Discord.js, but in my admin command, it throws this error when trying to add a player to a table:

C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\DiscCentral\bot.js:49
   if(ServerAdmins[1]) {
    ^

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
at Client.client.on (C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\DiscCentral\bot.js:49:20)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Client.emit (events.js:211:7)
at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\DiscCentral\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\DiscCentral\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\DiscCentral\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\DiscCentral\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\DiscCentral\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
```

Heres my code:

```
    if(command === 'admin') {
        if(message.member.roles.find("name", "Owner")){
            var ServerExists = false;
             for(var ServerId; ServerId<Admins.length; ServerId++) {
                if(Admins[ServerId] === message.member.server.id) {
                    ServerExists = true;
                }
             }
             if(ServerExists === false) {
                var NewServer = Admins[Admins.length + 1]
                NewServer = {};
             }
             for(var ServerId; ServerId<Admins.length; ServerId++) {
                 if(Admins[ServerId] === message.member.server.id) {
                     var ServerNumber = ServerId
                 }
             }
            var ServerAdmins = Admins[ServerNumber]
            if(ServerAdmins[1]) {
                ServerAdmins[1] = message.member.server.id;
            } else {
            ServerAdmins[ServerAdmins.length + 1] = message.member.server.id;
            message.reply(`${ServerAdmins[ServerAdmins.length]} was added.`)
        }       
    }
```

I'm assuming the problem is that I'm using a table inside of a table, but I don't know how to assign ranks to each server any other way.

Any suggestions on what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you declare the `Admins` variable in your code, at least the code that you presented. Show us how you define it? As right now, that would be why it's giving you errors.

Comment: Oops, I had forgot to add that.Here's my first five lines of code:    
 const Discord = require("discord.js");
 const client = new Discord.Client(); 
 const packagejson = require("./package.json"); 
 var Admins = {};
 var prefix = 'd!'
 var auth = require('./auth.json');